# Running homeassistant via shellscript

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, home-automation, home-assistant

I want to start homeassistant on startup or via shellscript. For some reason the run stops after the first command. Any help?

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u homeassistant -H -s
cd /srv/homeassistant
source bin/activate
hass
$SHELL
```

It just executes the first line and stops, no feedback on the commandline.

Comment: Are you trying to run `cd ...` onwards as user "homeassistant" ? Perhaps put those lines in a separate file and sudo to run that whole script ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to run 3 commands as user `homeassistant`, so try creating a new `bash` shell in which to run them and then do so like this:

```
sudo -u homeassistant bash -c 'cd /srv/homeassistant && source bin/activate && hass'
```